# Vue why props is undefined on component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I try to transfer data to my component using props
If I type the name in the parent, I see that the button is working properly, ie the problem is with the component.
Where am I wrong?

Thanks in advance

**Parent:**

**HTML**

```
<div><button @click="changeName" :name="name">Change my name</button></div>
```

**Script:**

```
import UserDetail from "./UserDetail.vue";
export default {
  components: {
    UserDetail,
    UserEdit,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      name: "Eden",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeName() {
      this.name = "EdenM";
    },
  },
};
```

**Component**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>{{ name }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["name"],
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ooooooh!! I add the prop an wrong place!
Here is my ans:

```
   <user-detail :name="name"></user-detail>
```

Comment: if `:name` is a prop, in the child component you need to spec it as prop: `props: ['name']` or `props: {name: String}`, or `props: { name: { type: String, required: true }}` or `props: { name: { type: String, default: ''}}` See [props](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html).

Comment: @edenm If you answered your own question, accept your answer so people seeing the question will know that it has already been answered.

Comment: @Tim Tnx,but I can accept answer to my Q only after 2 days :(

Comment: @tao - thanks for your comment.. the Vue3 documentation does not even tell you this how to do it on props i spent too much time on that

Comment: @PiotrKula, do you mean [prop validation](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#prop-validation)?